# Exposing application's codebase to the vagrant instance

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant, nupic

I'm trying to run an application using vagrant. I have a directory where the codebase of app is placed and the .vagrant dir that is created there after its initializing. It looks so:

```
[app_codebase_root]/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox
```

There is a some very short manual about what to do (https://github.com/numenta/nupic/wiki/Running-Nupic-in-a-Virtual-Machine) and I stopped at the point 9 where is said:

> 9) Expose [app] codebase to the vagrant instance... If you have the
>   codebase checkout out, you can copy or move it into the current
>   directory...

So it's not clear for me what to copy and where? Does it mean some place within vagrant (if yes, then which exactly?) or some another place? Or I should just make a command `vagrant ssh` now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Vagrant documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/index.html):

> By default, Vagrant will share your project directory (the directory with the **Vagrantfile**) to **/vagrant**.

So you should find your codebase root should under `/vagrant` on your guest.

Comment: Well, I suggested just so. I have run VirtualBox and it exposed to me this: folders: **/vagrant** path: **[app_root]** So I was confused because it seems that everything OK and I should just make command **vagrant ssh** exactly in app_root directory, right? But why there in the manual is said about copy code base if it is existed there already? Now is it enough to command **vagrant ssh*?

Comment: The manual says "If you have the codebase checkout out", but in your case is already "in". You don't have to copy anything. If your codebase had been in a different place you should have copied into the directory with the Vagrantfile.

Answer (score 0):

This is always going to be a little confusing, so you need to separate the concepts of the host system and the VM.

Let's say the shared directory (the one with the Vagrantfile) is [something]/vagrant *on your host system*. Copy your app directory to [something]/vagrant/nupic (or run git clone in that directory) *while still in Windows*. Check using Windows Explorer that you see all the source files.

In a console window, cd to [something]/vagrant and run vagrant ssh.

You are now in the VM, so everything is now the VM's filesystem. Your code is now in /vagrant/nupic. Edit .bashrc as per the instructions to point to this directory, and run the build commands.